# C/C++ Hook to access the window's elements of a program

Tags: c++, c, macros, window, hook

I'm trying to access window's elements of a program, of which I have only the binaries and installed stuff.

For example, I want to click on a certain item of a certain listbox in an automated way.

I'm only interested in  accessing one listbox of one window of the program, but this would help me create a very good macro (the list box is full of "expands", it's long, and dynamic).

I thought about using macros like Autohotkey, but quickly considered it a bad idea.

I don't even know how to call this, but i tried searching for "hook" related stuff, without success.

PS: I'm on a 64 bits Windows 7 system, using Code Blocks. Let me know if there is a better IDE for that, like VS, because i can use it too.

**EDIT**

Ok, so I caught the information of the window using WinSpy++, though I don't really know what to do with it. I'm trying to get the handle of the child window, but am failing.
I'm very noob at this. I reminded of an important detail, I need to get the names of the listbox elements and their positions (1st, 2nd, 3rd), is it possible?

**EDIT 2 (Where I am)**
Ok, here is where I am so far: I caught the main window handle, but can't get the handle of any of the children. My googling turned up a "GetDlgItem" function, but didn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: Sorry about the edit to your question; I edited the wrong thing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may be able to use Spy++ to find the specific class and/or caption for the window (the listbox control) and then target it via FindWindow().

If not, you'll have to find the app's main window, and traverse its children, looking for the children of the children until you find the listbox window.

Once you finally have the window handle, you can just PostMessage() the WM_CLICK message to it.

**EDIT 1 (For Meysam)**

I started by googling for [Listview window messages](https://www.google.com/search?q=listview+window+messages). That took me to [this MSDN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff485961(v=vs.85).aspx). Looking down through the list, [LVM_GETITEM](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774953(v=vs.85).aspx) stands out. It takes an [LVITEM structure](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774760(v=vs.85).aspx) as an LPARAM.

In that struct, the `iItem` member identifies the index. All that you need to know now is an item count, so that you can iterate through each index, and write code like this pseudocode:

```
for (int i = 0; i < item_count; i++)
{
    LVITEM lvi;
    lvi.iItem = i; // probably need to set other pieces of the struct
    LRESULT item = SendMessage(hwnd, LVM_GETITEM, NULL, (LPARAM)lvi);
}
```

For how many items (item_count), use [LVM_GETITEMCOUNT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761044(v=vs.85).aspx).

```
 LRESULT item_count = SendMessage(hwnd, LVM_GETITEMCOUNT, NULL, NULL);
```

Comment: Is it possible to access the listbox items? I would like to fetch their names and positions for example.

Comment: Send a LB_GETCOUNT to get that count, then: for (i = 0; i < count; i++) { send LB_GETITEMDATA or LB_GETTEXT } to get each item's data/text.

Comment: Ok, here is where i am so far: i caught the main window handle, but cant get the handle of any of the childs.  My googling turned up a "GetDlgItem" function, but didn't work. Any idea?

Comment: So, you're able to get the window handle of the parent of the listbox? Are you sure that the listbox isn't inside of a different parent? (Check spy++ to see if there are other windows between the main hwnd and the listbox.)

Comment: It's working now, im getting the handle of the listbox parent. Now i'm trying to use the LB_ commands you said.

Comment: So far i'm getting a -1 as a return from "SendMessage(hwnd3, LB_GETCOUNT, 0, 0)". The list bos has expandable buttons and the class is called "TAMTreeView", maybe this is important?

Comment: The class is called TAMTreeView and has expandable buttons? Are you sure is a listbox? It sounds like a treeview. If so, you can use TVM_GETCOUNT and TVM_GETITEM in the same way.

Comment: did you finally get the items because I have same issue. @Lynn how can I know to send which message to get what ? I saw the list of message I can send to a window but its a huge list and confusing.

Comment: @Meysam For which type of control?

Comment: I mean in general. For example if I am looking for a list view how should I find the proper message ?

Comment: @Meysam I edited the question... hopefully that helps.

Answer (score 2):

Hook is what you want.

First, your **hook callback function** should reside in a DLL, so that Window can inject your code into an other program's process space.

Second, you should register your hook with some events, such as mouse move/click events, using SetWindowsHookEx() API.

Then you can fully access to the listbox.

Tip: you could use a little tool called **MS Spy++** to get the ID or name of the listbox.

Comment: Is it possible to access the listbox elements like that? Get their names and positions (1st, 2nd, 3rd).

By the way, i used WinSpy++ to get the information you mentioned, now i'm trying to find information on your tips, as i'm a total when it comes to this subject.